# FreeMarker template engine will support PDF, XML, CSV, XLS formats?

Tags: freemarker

FreeMarker template engine will support PDF, XML, CSV, XLS formats? or it will support only HTML format alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freemarker supports other format than HTML, Moreover you can define other [outputformat](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_outputformat.html):

> Sets the output format to the specified one, inside the nested block.

While XML is one of the [predefined formats](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html#topic.predefinedOutputFormats):

HTML,XHTML,XML,JavaScript,JSON,CSS and more.

Comment: It's depend on version.can you post new question?